# looping through two array to replace one value in array for specific match

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've two arrays like below

```
flag: true
firstName: "user1"
lastName: "usr1"

flag: true
firstName: "user2"
lastName: "usr2"

flag: true
firstName: "user3"
lastName: "usr3"
```

And the other one like below

```
"user1"
"user2"
```

My intention is, the second array value matches the first array with firstname then needs to override flag with false.

I'm expecting a result like

```
flag: false
firstName: "user1"
lastName: "usr1"

flag: false
firstName: "user2"
lastName: "usr2"

flag: true
firstName: "user3"
lastName: "usr3"
```

Note: If firstname is not matched. I don't want to change the flag value. –

Any good way to achieve this in react,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider:

array 1 = users

array 2 = userNames

Then:
This one will change the flag to true if user.firstName exist in userNames, else to false

```
users.map((user) => ({...user, flag: !userNames.includes(user.firstName)}))
```

This will return you the new array

If you do not want to change the flag if firstName does not match, then:

```
users.map((user) => userNames.includes(user.firstName) ? ({...user, flag: false}) : user)
```

Comment: Lets check this

Comment: userNames.includes() will look for whole matching items, in this case they are objects. It won't work.

Comment: userNames are not objects?! They are strings

Comment: String array as far as I can parse the OP

Comment: yes 2nd array is list of string

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question right.

Comment: @OktayYuzcan Its not working, my first array has 50 entries. And 2nd array has 5 to 10 elements. In this code when I'm trying the 0th element flag is getting changed. Other entries remains same even if firstname of both array same.

Comment: If firstname is not matched. I dont want to change the flag value.

Comment: You are not doing something right or your question is not clear. This should work if you have 2 arrays, one of them is array of objects and the second one is array of strings, index of elements does not matter. If an element from array 2 matches firstName of an object from array 1, it should change it to false, else to true. It returns a new array, not changing the first one

Comment: I updated the answer if you do not want to change the flag if userName does not exist in userNames

Comment: yes you are right, Let you know how it goes.

Comment: The second one is working for my condition. thanks a lot. Accepted the answer.